# Illegal choice error in log file

Tags: 7, views

I got this error in my log file.  It was on a select element for an exposed View filter:

Illegal choice 24alert(0) in field_item_type_tid element.

Is it someone trying to hack my site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone (or something) is trying to submit a value for field_item_type_tid that isn't in the list of allowed options for that field (as prepared by the form API prior to rendering the form/element).

The FAPI is objecting to that attempt (as it should; it's a security feature), so the user will receive the standard "Illegal choice" error message.

It might be an attempt at a hack, it might be something weird instigated by a user/browser extension, or it might be the result of some javascript trying to change the allowed values on the client-side, without informing the backend that the options need to change.

Without analysing the page and all the involved parameters it's only speculation, though. It might be being caused by any of the above, or perhaps some other external factor.

Comment: Thanks Clive.  It was a select drop down list of specific, and somehow several attempts at stuffing some JavaScript as a parameter for the filter of that view, so it looks like a hack attempt.  I blocked the IP address.